# kmean clustering: variable selection

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm applying a kmean algorithm for clustering my customer base. I'm struggling conceptually on the selection process of the dimensions (variables) to include in the model. I was wondering if there are methods established to compare among models with different variables. In particular, I was  thinking to use the common SSwithin / SSbetween ratio, but I'm not sure if that can be applied to compare models with a different number of dimensions... 
Any suggestions>?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic approaches are sequential selection algorithms like "sequential floating forward selection" (SFFS) or "sequential floating backward elimination (SFBS). Those are heuristic methods where you eliminate (or add) one feature at the time based on your performance metric, e.g,. mean squared error (MSE). Also, you could use a genetic algorithm for that if you like.

Here is an easy-going paper that summarizes the ideas:
[Feature Selection from Huge Feature Sets](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/pubserv/pubs/Bins-draper-publications-bins_iccv01.pdf)

And a more advanced one that could be useful: [Unsupervised Feature Selection for the k-means Clustering Problem](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/mmahoney/pubs/NIPS09.pdf)

EDIT:
When I think about it again, I initially had the question in mind "how do I select the *k* (a fixed number) best features (where k < d)," e.g., for computational efficiency or visualization purposes. Now, I think what you where asking is more like "What is the feature subset that performs best overall?" The silhouette index (similarity of points within a cluster) could be useful, but I really don't think you can really improve the performance via feature selection unless you have the ground truth labels.

I have to admit that I have more experience with supervised rather than unsupervised methods. Thus, I typically prefer regularization over feature selection/dimensionality reduction when it comes to tackling the "curse of dimensionality." I use dimensionality reduction frequently for data compression though.

Comment: thanks a lot Sebastian. Do you know of any R package that have these algorithms already implemented and ready to use? Thanks a lot

Comment: In the specific case of kmean clustering, what would be the right metric to use for model selection? I fear that using criteria based on the sum of square of within and between cluster distance may be dangerous as the metric may be dependend on the number of dimensions. Am I saying a stupid thing?

Comment: @lilloraffa Yes, I think so too with regards of the performance metrics. I didn't mean to use it to compare different clusterings with different dimensions but to compare feature subsets for a fixed dimension. I am not sure if it is possible to compare the performance of your clustering depending on the dimensionality without having the ground truth labels.

Comment: @lilloraffa regarding the R packages: I have to admit that I switched from R and Python a long time ago. Simple things like SFFS or SBFS can be simply implemented but for learning algorithms I typically use scikit-learn since it is better optimized (faster). But they also have some feature selection algos implemented if you find it useful: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html

Comment: might be a bit late but just wanted to mention the sparcl package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sparcl/index.html